# How to access/change the default deployment path in Azure App Service by GitHub Actions?

Tags: python, azure, github, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

Actually I have a working code deployed into Azure App Service. Based on the user's response I am creating a log folder using os.mkdir("logs") function of Python.

Is there any way to get that "logs" folder from Azure App service?

I tried multiple ways like getting the source code from Azure App sevice using FTPS credentials - Since the deployment happens by GitHub Actions that "site/repository" folder is empty.

My understanding is even if that folder has the contents since the deployed code is from some location which can be accessed only by GitHub actions, I cannot get my "logs" folder.

Can anyone help me by suggesting a solution for this?
It can be either modifying the github actions to deploy code from a location which can be accessed or any other mechanisms to get my "logs" folder.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

As Azure App service is a PAAS, Platform as a service. Accessing logs directly from File system is not recommended. As Azure App Service has its built in logging services. Like Application Insights. Instead of using `os.mkdir("logs")` You can make use of third party libraries like `Opencensus` to write logs to application insights and implement the logging logic to application insights in your Web app code, Like given in this [**Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opencensus-python).

I can find the real time logs via Log stream and Deployment logs via Kudu. Refer below:-

The Log stream will give you live logs of the Web app start up and any errors if exist while starting the app.

[image]

You can also enable App service logs like below:-

[image]

You can visit Development Tools > Advanced Tools > Go and check the Logs inside Kudu tool like below:-

[image]

*Download the Logs zip folder and inspect the Logs in that folder.*

*You can access your deployed source code files and logs file if it is created in the site wwwroot in the kudu tool above.* If it is not created use the built in logging options as Log stream and Kudu tool.

Additionally, You can retrieve the Logs by calling these API's one for [**Diagnostic Logging**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/get-diagnostic-logs-configuration) and another for  [**Container Logs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/get-container-logs-zip)

You can also enable Diagnostic Logging and store it inside a Storage account or Log analytics instead of using File system to access logs. you can set retention period on the Logs in your Diagnostic settings.

Store the Logs in Log analytics and query the logs:-

[image]

Store the Logs in Storage account or Event Hub:-

[image]

**Reference:-**

[Enable diagnostics logging - Azure App Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs)